# How to change the height and width of document editor in KeystoneJs 6?

Tags: keystonejs, keystonejs6

I am new to keystonejs, and creating a post page using the below code.
but the size of the document editor is too small and whenever i add a component block, it kind of jumps.

Its hard to edit on the small editor window, clicking on the "expand" button also not helping much.
how to increase the default height and width of the document editor?

````
  fields: {
    title: text({ validation: { isRequired: true } }),
    slug: text({ isIndexed: "unique", validation: { isRequired: true } }),
    content: document({
      formatting: true,
      dividers: true,
      links: true,
      layouts: [
        [1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1],
      ],
      ui: {
        views: path.join(process.cwd(), "./src/component-blocks/post"),
      },
      componentBlocks,
    }),
  },
});```
````